# exe memory size does not increase much in taskbar when run from java program

Tags: java

I am running an executeable from java(1.8) on Windows 7

```
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\Demo\\pvaroptimizer\\bin\\pvaroptimizer.exe","-p",importantInfo[0],"D:\\Demo\\pvaroptimizer\\bin\\New structure.pvz").start();

    while(process.isAlive())
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The exeucteable runs properly but the exe which normally takes 3 Gb space in memory(checked in the taskbar) when run from commmand prompt, now reaches a maximum of 30 mb space only, hence slowing down the execution. Can someone please help me to know about this limitation.

Comment: Are you sure that execution is slowed down not halted. Do you application (`pvaroptimizer.exe`) print somsing to console?

Comment: It is an external exe, We dont get a command prompt when we run from java. I checked in the taskbar, the memory slowly increases till around 30 mb, no further. It takes exceptional amount of time but does not complete. As soon as I kill the process (the above code) suddenly the size of the pvaroptimier memory increases quickly (i saw in taskbar) and it completes execution successfully.

Comment: If you run it from command line does it produce logs?

Comment: It does but on the command prompt

Comment: It is common problem. Give me a minute I find solution for you.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proble is that `pvaroptimizer.exe` write to output, but output buffer have limited size. When buffer is full `pvaroptimizer.exe` blocks until there is free space in buffer.

Next code should solve this problem.

```
    Process process = null;
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\Demo\\pvaroptimizer\\bin\\pvaroptimizer.exe", "-p", importantInfo[0], "D:\\Demo\\pvaroptimizer\\bin\\New structure.pvz");

        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        process = builder.start();

        InputStream stream = process.getInputStream();
        while(stream.read()!=-1){}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```